# Spreading covid talking vs breathing risks

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, covid

Some [links](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/coronavirus-covid-19-breathing-talking-enough-spread-airborne) claim one can spread covid merely by breathing (not talking):

> Currently available research supports the possibility that SARS-CoV-2
> could be spread via bioaerosols generated directly by patients’
> exhalation

My question is: if someone say person A enters a room which activity carries more risk in terms of becoming infected from person A:

- activity 1: A is silent in room all time
- activity 2: A talks

Answer (score 3):

Activity 2 carries more risk of transmission : talking is associated with more droplets being exhaled in the room's air.

However, Activity 1 cannot be considered as completely devoid of droplet generation.

This article published in Nature gives informations on aerosol transmission  https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-020-69286-3